# Variable does not get assigned while reading data from json

Tags: javascript, d3.js, assign

I am using following code to read data from json using D3 and passing this to another function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple venn.js example</title>
</head>
<style>
div {
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="weighted_example"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../venn.js"></script>


<script>
    var sets= [{}];
    d3.json( "json", function( data ) 
    {  
       sets=data;        // reading successfully
    });

    alert(sets);    // but i need to use alert to pass the value to function div.datum(sets) otherwise sets value is null.
    var div =d3.select("#weighted_example")
    div.datum(sets).call(venn.VennDiagram())
</script>
</html>
```

json file:

### [ { "sets": [0], "size": 1958 }, { "sets": [1], "size": 1856 }, { "sets": [2], "size": 1297 }, { "sets": [0, 1], "size": 220 }, { "sets": [2, 0], "size": 123 }, { "sets": [2, 1], "size": 139 } ]

logically it seems to unrealistic. When i use alert in the d3.json() function it shows the correct values so sets values already been assigned but why null values are passed if i don't use alert for sets. How can i fix such error?

Answer (score 1):

`d3.json` is an asynchronous function, thus you can not be sure that sets will be ready when you arrive at the `div.datum` line.

The reason why you see it working with alert is because alert will stop the flow of your javascript, thus sets will have had a value attributed.

You should put your datum code inside the `d3.json` code.